# Building a List in LISP from the atoms of another list

Tags: lisp

Define  the function 'mapping' that takes 2 arguments: a SIMPLE list L, and an integer value val. Every element of the list L is a  list of two atoms – key and object. The function returns a list of  objects whose key is less than val.

Example:
(mapping '((12 k) (7 n) (23 r) (9 p)) 13) --> (k n p)

My Code So Far:

```
(defun mapping (list val)
    (if (consp list)  ;;if list is not empty
        (if (> val (caar list)) ;; check the first value in the first nested list
            (cons (car(cdr list)));;if value is greater add that value to the return list

    (mapping (cdr list) val)))) ;; recurse thru the list
```

My code has syntax erros  as well as the cons statement is not returning the list of all the values of how i expect it.

Comment: Since this is an assignment, I'm not giving a completel answer `(cons (car(cdr list)))`- `cons` takes two arguments. You've giving only one. What would make a good second argument?

Comment: The second argument should be the remaining keys whose values are less than val.

Comment: Right. So there's a change you need to make...

Answer (score 0):

It's really easy to write what you want using high-order functions, you don't need all this nested IFs.

```
(defun mapping (list val)
  (mapcan
    (lambda (el)
      (if (> val (car el))
        (cdr el)
        nil))
    list))

CL-USER> (mapping '((12 k) (7 n) (23 r) (9 p)) 13)
(K N P)
```

If you have to wtite recursice one:

```
(defun recursive-mapping (list val)
  (cond
    ((null list) nil)
    ((> val (caar list)) (cons (cadar list)
                               (recursive-mapping (cdr list) val)))
    (t (recursive-mapping (cdr list) val))))

CL-USER> (recursive-mapping '((12 k) (7 n) (23 r) (9 p)) 20)
(K N P)
```

Comment: Unfortunately i cannot use higher-order function because we have not learned such function in LISP. I do not know what lambda or mapcan is.

Comment: @RodEden, you not allowed to look in documetation? I added recursive variant for you any way, see edited answer.

Comment: @coredump, it's clearly an assignment. For pedagogical reasons, the assessor presumably wants the student to use the features they've learnt so far. Which is reasonable.